# hold position of FILE pointer before fseek()

Tags: c, file-io, fseek

I am trying to write a C function that reads the first line of text from a file, then uses `fseek()` and `ftell()` to get the size of the remainder of the file (the file minus the first line).

My idea was to use a second `FILE *fp1` to grab the position of the original `FILE *fp`, and send `fp1` to the end of the file with `fseek()`, so that I wouldn't have to move my original `fp` and lose its position.

Here's my code. The compiler is telling me I can't assign `fp1` to `fp` because `fp1` is a `FILE*` and `fp` is a `struct FILE*`.

Can I achieve what I'm trying to do this way?

```
 FILE *fp, fp1;
 fp = fopen(filename, "r");
 if (!fp)
     return 0;

 fscanf(fp, "%1d", m); //Lines 15-18 read the first line of the file
 fscanf(fp, "%*1c");
 fscanf(fp, "%1d", n);
 fscanf(fp, "%*1c");
 fp1 = fp;         //<---------- This is my problem.
                   //how do I set fp1 to the same place in the
                   //file as fp?

 fseek(fp1, 0, SEEK_END);
 *file_size = ftell(fp1);
```

Comment: You can fix the compile error by declaring `fp1` correctly as a pointer - the `*` is missing. That is `FILE *fp, *fp1;`. But that is not the right way to save the file position (both pointers will refer to the same opened stream and hence same file position).

Comment: Do not post code with line numbers, it is inconvenient to cut and paste for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition does not define 2 `FILE *` pointers:

```
FILE *fp, fp1;
```

`fp` is a `FILE *`, but `fp1` is defined as a `FILE` type.

You cannot define `FILE` objects this way, they should only be obtained from `fopen()`.  Their state cannot be saved by making a copy of the `FILE` object, it is way too complex for this and uses other resources in addition to the `FILE` object, which may be an incomplete type.

The good news is you can save the current offset in `fp` with `ftell()` and seek to the end to attempt to get the file size, and then restore the stream position with another call to `fseek()`:

```
long saved = ftell(fp);
*file_size = -1;  // file size may be impossible to retrieve
if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) != -1) {
    *file_size = ftell(fp);
}
fseek(fp, saved, SEEK_SET);
```

But you should note that this method is not reliable:

- it is not guaranteed for text files.
- it may not work for devices, pipes, the terminal, special files...

You should try and modify your method so it does not need to know the file size.

Comment: I incorporated your error checking, thanks. If I were using C++ I would be looking for eof with cin.peek(), but I am not as proficient with C. Does using fopen() maintain a similar eof flag? I suppose my further questions about this are not necessarily a part of this question.

Comment: `fopen` does not *maintain* an eof flag.  In C, you only know you are at the end of a stream by attempting to read from the `FILE*`.  You can write this: `int peekc(FILE*fp) { int c = getc(fp); if (c != EOF) ungetc(c, fp); return c; }` and use `if (peekc(fp) == EOF)` as a test for end of file.

Answer (score 5):

This just copies the pointer to file handle. The proper way is to save ftell result before you move, and after moving to end of file - move back again.

So:

```
long saved = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
*file_size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, saved, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Won't the last call to fseek() with the SEEK_SET argument reset fp right back to the beginning of the file? I am trying not to do that.

Comment: Nevermind, I see that you've put saved in as an offset. I used your suggestion and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Be aware that this method is not a reliable way to get the file size.  It does not work for devices, pipes, the terminal... and it is not guaranteed for text files.